# Complete 3-by-5 Crossword Puzzle

Tags: word, crosswords, word-square

Looking for a grid with five letters horizontally, three words vertically, and eight words in total.

All 8 words must be easy words; it must not be necessary to check the dictionary.

I tried the following, but although CREAM EAGLE EMPTY was successful, not so much across, with the exception of ALT and RAM.

> **CEE**
>
> **RAM**
>
> **EGP**
>
> **ALT**
>
> **MEY**

Comment: I'd argue that "cee" is a (well known) word but is alt a word (rather than an abbreviation, say)?

Comment: The word " ALT " was used to describe the keyboard ALT key. I think it knows better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

> ```
>      H A P P Y       M E A N S       R E P L Y
>      A G R E E       A R G U E       A G R E E
>      D O O R S       P R O N E       G O O D S
>
>      L E A S T       R E A C T       S T E A L
>      A G R E E       A R G U E       H E N C E
>      W O M A N       G R E E N       E N D E D
>
>      L E A S T       R E A D Y       T R E A T
>      A R G U E       A R G U E       E A R T H
>      G R E E N       T R E E S       A G R E E
> ```

Okay, I'll admit ...

> ... that I've written a program to find the grids. I think the used words are okay. I've used the [SCOWL](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) word lists to find good words. These lists consist of several lists, ordered by category and also by frequency. It is easy to omit abbreviations. For the 3-letter words I've used the 20-percentile English words; for the 5 letter words I've used the 10-percentile English words.
>
>  You can [run the program online](https://ideone.com/peArNE) (with hardcoded word lists) and generate the results above.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

> `B O N E S`
>  `I N U R E`
>  `T E N E T`

Three 5-letter words:

> BONES, INURE, TENET.

Five 3-letter words:

> BIT, ONE, NUN, ERE, SET.

Answer (score 4):

> `D A M E S`
>  `A P A R T`
>  `D E C A Y`

The one I'm not so happy with is

> mac or MAC

but it's still legitimate.

Comment: "Mac" looks good to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackintosh